# Add listener to TableViewer editing column

Tags: java, swt, jface, keylistener, tableviewer

Is it possible to add a listener to the column where editing is enabled?

I enabled editing support and would like to add a keylistener to be able to track live changes but I can't find anything

Comment: Are you using `EditingSupport` for the editing support? What cell editor are you using?

Comment: I have a TableViewerColumn where i set         myCol.setEditingSupport(new TranslationTextEditingSupport(tableViewer)); then the editing is enabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `EditingSupport` class is using the `TextCellEditor` you can replace that with a class extending `TextCellEditor` to gain access to the `Text` control and various predefined methods.

The `Text` control in `TextCellEditor` is stored in a field called `text` which you can access from your sub-class.

`TextCellEditor` already has a key listener and defines a:

```
protected void keyReleaseOccured(KeyEvent keyEvent)
```

method that you can override. Be sure to call `super.keyReleaseOccured(keyEvent)` if you override this as there is  important code in this method.

Comment: I have editing support on a column when I enter a character to the already available text for the first character it does not detect changes but when I add more it detects it , I am using keyreleasedOccured method and trying to get the text like this String expression = super.text.getText();